# Store all items from filename to another then return that file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

So lets say i was given a function to store whatever is in one filename to a different file name, how would i do that?

```
def return_newfile(self, filename):

    ......
    .....
    ....
    self.return_newfile(data)
```

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you just looking to make a copy of a file?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do what I believe you want.

```
file1 = open("filename1","r")
file1_contents = file1.read()
file1.close()

file2 = open("filename2","w")
file2.write(file1_contents)
file2.close()
```

Now, there may be a better way to do what you want, like if you just want to copy a file without doing anything to the contents in between. However, if you want to process the contents, this is probably the way to go.

Comment: I think this is a poor way to copy a file. It is both, technically inferior (exception unsafe, prone to memory exhaustion) and more complicated than using the ready-made `shutil.copyfile`.